# How to separate information sent to two computers under same ip

Tags: php, ip, cart, multiple-users

I am trying to make a cart system using PHP. My cart system allows users to add products to their cart and save it there without having to login (as a guest) simply by referring to the user IP. Some of you already know where this is going.

Now lets consider that two different people connect from the same network (using same IP) on two different computers and try to visit my cart system. The first person adds a product to cart and thinks about getting or not it over night.

While the first person is thinking over night, the second person connects to the other computer (under same network) and adds an item to the cart. The second person realizes that there is an extra item in the cart that he/she did not add.

I tried separating it by getting external ip then using local ip to separate computers, but that seemed foolish because you cant use local ip if its not hosted on a local server.

I don't want the customers to login before using cart. A lot of ecommerce sites have figured out a way to allow customers to update cart from multiple computers under the same network without any of the computers interfering with one another's results (displayed items in cart).

Comment: Afaik other sites use sessions for this

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't identify individuals via IP address at all for the very reason you mentioned — multiple users can be on the same network. Instead, use [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) or [cookies](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) to store this information. Since you want to store this information past the point when a user would close their browser window, you should use cookies as they are more persistent.

An example of how to store cart details in a cookie could look something like this:

```
<?php
setcookie("cart", "item, another item, yet another item", time()+3600*24*365*10, '/');
?>
```

Then you can use `explode` to get all the items.

```
<?php
foreach (explode(",", $_COOKIE['cart']) as $item) {
  echo trim($item); // Will output each item in the cookie cart
}
?>
```

---

Alternatively, if you want to store each item in a separate cookie, you could also do it like this:

```
<?php
// It doesn't matter what you name the cookies in this case as you will be looping through all of them, you just need a unique string
setcookie("item 1", "item name 1", time()+3600*24*365*10, '/');
setcookie("item 2", "item name 2", time()+3600*24*365*10, '/');
setcookie("item 3", "item name 3", time()+3600*24*365*10, '/');
// Need page reload to access cookies
foreach ($_COOKIE as $item) {
  echo $item;
}
?>
```

Important note about cookies: You can **not** access a cookie at the same time you are setting it; you must have a page reload in between.

Comment: An important addendum: Not only will multiple users often share the same IP, but a single user's IP will sometimes change. This is particularly common for mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

Never use ip for identify the user! Use a cookie instead.